# Rails code executing twice when in production mode

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm running Ruby on Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.8.7.

I have an issue with code executing twice when in production mode. Rails is saving the data twice in the table so it creates redundancy.

Here is my controller:

```
  def admission1
  user = current_user
  @student = Student.new(params[:student])
  @selected_value = Configuration.default_country 
  @application_sms_enabled = SmsSetting.find_by_settings_key("ApplicationEnabled")
  @last_admitted_student = Student.find(:last)
  @config = Configuration.find_by_config_key('AdmissionNumberAutoIncrement')
  @categories = StudentCategory.active
  @batches = Batch.active


  if request.post?
    #add student multiple course
    student_batch = params[:student][:batch_id]
    if !student_batch.blank? 
      student_batch.each do |c|
        batch = Batch.find c
        @student.batches << batch unless @student.batches.include? batch
      end
        if @config.config_value.to_i == 1
          @exist = Student.find_by_admission_no(params[:student][:admission_no])
          if @exist.nil?
            @status = @student.save
          else 
              @last_admitted_student = Student.find(:last)
              @student.admission_no = @last_admitted_student.admission_no.next
              @status = @student.save
          end          
        else
          @status = @student.save
        end
    else 
      flash[:notice] = "#{t('insert_batch_record')}"
      redirect_to :controller => "student", :action => "admission1", :id => @student.id
    end

  end
end
```

As you can see, I'm trying to save the student model in the database however Rails is saving the student_batches twice. Here is the log:

```
Processing StudentController#admission1 (for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-09 21:56:06) [POST]
Parameters: {"action"=>"admission1", "student"=>{"email"=>"", "nationality_id"=>"77", "blood_group"=>"", "state"=>"", "address_line2"=>"", "address_line1"=>"", "student_category_id"=>"", "date_of_birth"=>"2010-11-09", "last_name"=>"", "admission_no"=>"0857", "middle_name"=>"", "gender"=>"m", "country_id"=>"77", "city"=>"", "birth_place"=>"", "batch_id"=>["2"], "first_name"=>"alitia", "phone2"=>"", "phone1"=>"", "pin_code"=>"", "religion"=>"", "admission_date"=>"2015-11-09"}, "controller"=>"student", "commit"=>"► Simpan & Lanjutkan", "authenticity_token"=>"p0NPObfIvU0IjS8NlfKOEfDT5m8I7L0Yt9y8RntjF3Y="}
[4;36;1mUser Columns (2.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSHOW FIELDS FROM `users`[0m
[4;35;1mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0mSELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 1) [0m
[0m
[4;36;1mStudent Create (1.0ms)[0m   [0;1mINSERT INTO `students` (`class_roll_no`, `is_deleted`, `created_at`, `student_batches_id`, `language`, `email`, `photo_data`, `user_id`, `ward_id`, `blood_group`, `nationality_id`, `is_sms_enabled`, `date_of_birth`, `student_category_id`, `address_line1`, `address_line2`, `state`, `updated_at`, `admission_no`, `last_name`, `is_active`, `has_paid_fees`, `middle_name`, `immediate_contact_id`, `photo_file_name`, `photo_file_size`, `gender`, `status_description`, `batch_id`, `birth_place`, `city`, `country_id`, `first_name`, `photo_content_type`, `admission_date`, `religion`, `pin_code`, `phone1`, `phone2`) VALUES(NULL, 0, '2015-11-09 14:56:06', NULL, NULL, '', NULL, 24, NULL, '', 77, 1, '2010-11-09', NULL, '', '', '', '2015-11-09 14:56:06', '0857', '', 1, 0, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'm', NULL, 1, '', '', 77, 'alitia', NULL, '2015-11-09', '', '', '', '')[0m
[4;35;1mStudentBatch Columns (2.0ms)[0m   [0mSHOW FIELDS FROM `student_batches`[0m

#here is the problems, it create batch load batch and create another batch. It is supposed to insert the batch only once

[4;36;1mStudentBatch Create (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mINSERT INTO `student_batches` (`student_id`, `created_at`, `has_fees`, `updated_at`, `batch_id`) VALUES(16, '2015-11-09 14:56:06', 1, '2015-11-09 14:56:06', 2)[0m
[4;35;1mStudentBatch Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0mSELECT * FROM `student_batches` WHERE (`student_batches`.student_id = 16) [0m
[4;36;1mStudentBatch Create (0.3ms)[0m   [0;1mINSERT INTO `student_batches` (`student_id`, `created_at`, `has_fees`, `updated_at`, `batch_id`) VALUES(16, '2015-11-09 14:56:06', 1, '2015-11-09 14:56:06', 2)[0m
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[4;35;1mSQL (79.6ms)[0m   [0mCOMMIT[0m
[4;36;1mSmsSetting Load (1.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT * FROM `sms_settings` WHERE (`sms_settings`.`settings_key` = 'ApplicationEnabled') LIMIT 1[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/student/admission1_2/16
Completed in 374ms (DB: 100) | 302 Found [http://localhost/student/admission1]
```

I've truncate some of the log so you can see the problem clearly. In the log, you can see Rails saves the student batch twice while in the code I'm saving only once.

If you need the models, please let me know. Btw, I'm using Fedena 2.3.5.

Comment: Are you really using Rails 2.x or was this lost in translation?

Comment: The formatting is inconsistent and you have some serious refactoring to do here before anyone is going to want to read that mess. I bet if you were to refactor this, your problem would become apparent.

Comment: @AntarrByrd Yes, I'm using rails 2.3.5. What make you confuse? Maybe I can help.

Comment: That's quite a method.

Comment: @michaelch I would suggest that you upgrade to rails 3.2.x or 4.2.x. Rails 2.x is very old and amount you ability to find support for issues will be greatly hindered by using such an old version. The last version or 2.x (2.3.8) was released in March of 2013. Any guides you are reading or probably not targeted at 2.x.

Comment: @AntarrByrd Hello, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I'm using Fedena 2.3. which is still using rails 2.3. It takes a lot of time to modify the whole code to be compatible with rails 3 or 4. The code runs perfectly on development mode but not in production mode. It saves the batch twice when running in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
student_batch.each do |c|
    batch = Batch.find c
    @student.batches << batch unless @student.batches.include? batch
end
```

Change this to

```
batches=[]
student_batch.each do |c|
        batch = Batch.find c
        batches << batch unless @student.batches.include? batch
end
@student.batches=batches
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. However the code removes student batch and as a result, when I try to save the student, it is conflicting with my validate_presence on student model. It is not saving because it detect that the student batch is null.

Comment: probably you are using the validation student belongs_to :batch . but here you are sending array of batches . you may need to change association structure